# c socket: send() send only 1 byte at a time

Tags: c, sockets

I have the following program, that has to read a file 1MB at a time, send it to a server (always 1MB at a time) and get back an hash code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "Socket.h"
#include "../utils.h"

char *prog_name;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd, hash, n=atoi(argv[3]);
    char buffer[1048576];
    Socket socket=SCreate(TCP);
    Connect(socket, argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));
    fd=open(argv[4], O_RDONLY);
    if(read(fd, buffer, 1048576)<1048576)
        return 1;
    while(n>0) {
        Send(socket, buffer, n);
        read(fd, buffer, 1048576);
        n--;
    }
    RecvN(socket, &hash, 4);
    printf("%d", ntohl(hash));
    return 0;
}
```

The Send function is defined as:

```
void Send(Socket socket, void *buffer, int buflen) {
    int nleft, nsent;
    for(nleft=buflen; nleft>0;) {
        if((nsent=send(socket->sockfd, buffer, nleft, 0))<=0) {
            perror("Send error");
            exit(-1);
        } else {
            nleft-=nsent;
            buffer+=nsent;
        }
    }
}
```

Where Socket is a pointer to a struct containing the socket file descriptor and others informations.

I've tried to print nsent at each iteration, and I've discovered that the socket send function send only 1 byte at a time, so to transfer 1MB it takes lot of time.

Which can be the problem?

Comment: Show command line that you use to launch program.

Comment: ./a.out 127.0.0.1 1994 1 ../../tools/big_file.txt ;
so argv[1] is the server IP, argv[2] is the server port, argv[3] is the number of MB to read from the file and argv[4] is the file name

Comment: `n=atoi(argv[3])`, and this `n` you are passing to `Send()` as `buflen`. I guess you just forgot to multiple it to `1024 * 1024`.

Comment: You are right. Stupid error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You pass in the value `1` (the value of `n`) into `Send` as `buflen`, so it only sends one byte at a time.

If `n` is the number of megabytes, you need to multiply this value by 1048576 when you call the function:

```
Send(socket, buffer, n * 1048576);
```